# Response token type in swift

Tags: swift, decode

The response from server format like this.

```
{
    "token": "..."
}
```

What type I should use to decode from data?

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    if let data = data {
        if let decodeToken = try? JSONDecoder().decode(WhatIsTheTokenType.self, from: data) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                ...
            }

            return
        }
    }

    print("Fetch failed: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
}.resume()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
 if let decodeToken = try? JSONDecoder().decode([String:String].self, from: data) {
    print(decodeToken["token"])
 }
```

or

```
 if let decodeToken = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String:String] {
    print(decodeToken["token"])
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should better define your own *response token type*.

```
struct ResponseToken: Codable {
    var token: String
}
```

And use it as:

```
        if let decodeToken = try? JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseToken.self, from: data) {
            print(decodeToken.token)
            //...
        }
```